What is the smallest number of clues needed to solve any standard 9x9 sudoku trivially
I define 'trivially' as being able to write every digit down in one operation, only considering that digit, without making pencil marks. The sort of problem you might give to a 5 year old. I hope the examples below will clarify.
In the centre board, the upper left 4 blocks have only one cell missing, which are filled in first. Then complete the eight top rows, then finally the columns.
In the more aggressively punctured right hand board, the six blocks are completed first. While the three blank blocks require both a row and column condition to complete, there is only one intersecting row/column that can accept any given digit. You can hover your pencil over each block while asking 'where does the '1' go?' and so on.
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 .      . . . 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3     4 . 6 7 . 9 1 2 .      . . . 7 . 9 1 . 3
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6     7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 .      . . . 1 2 3 4 5 6
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .      9 1 2 . . . 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2     3 . 5 6 . 8 9 1 .      3 . 5 . . . 9 . 2
6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5     6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 .      6 7 8 . . . 3 4 5
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7     8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 .      8 9 1 2 3 4 . . .
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1     2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .      2 . 4 5 . 7 . . . 
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4     . . . . . . . . .      5 6 7 8 9 1 . . .

It's not clear to me whether I can remove any more clues, and still be able to solve any board, without resorting to 'doing the puzzle' with pencil marks and deductions. I am specifically after a puncturing pattern that will work regardless of the actual data in the solution.
Can any more clues be removed, and the board solved in a 'write each number down once' trivial way?

Does this question solve your problem?

Yes, same question. It didn't come up in my searches, or the board's suggestions of similar ones when I was posting. Thanks.
